# simple RewriteRule pattern not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^committees([^/]*)$ /committees/view.cfm?c=$1 [L]
```

So any requests to:

http://www.acme.org/committees/12345abcd
are routed to
http://www.acme.org/committees/view.cfm?c=12345abcd

The rule never seems to match, though! Can someone shed some light?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should specify a `RewriteBase` and add a slash after committees.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^committees/([^/]*)$ /committees/view.cfm?c=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I get an error with your RewriteRule ^committees/([^/]*)$ /committees/view.cfm?c=$1 [L]

Comment: I figured it out. Here is the working code:  RewriteRule ^committees/(.*) /committees/view.cfm?c=$1 [L]